# How to fix "create-react-native-app is not recognized as internal or external command,operable program or batch file" issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm-install

I am new to building android app using react-native.I installed nodejs,npm(added the path variable as well),android studio,setup the sdk as required and create-react-native-app(using npm install -g create-react-native-app) as instructed in facebook github page.
When i tried creating new project with command "create-react-native-app" it shows that create-react-native-app isnot recognized as........... .Then i tried adding path in the user variable as well as system variables.But nothing seems to work.

I am on windows 8.1

Comment: which OS are you on?

Comment: i am on windows 8.1

Comment: did you run node in a separate command prompt and run the command?? Also are you inside the proper folder?

Comment: no i didnt run node separately.what is the command to run node for such cases.

Comment: I think you are combine expo and react native init project building process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a project using expo then there is no need to android studio or Xcode setup because of expo compile code on to the cloud.

**Create a project using expo**

**Step 1**

Install node.js

**Step 2.**

Install the Expo CLI command line utility**

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

**Step 3.**

Using the following command you can create first react native project

```
expo init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject npm start 

you can also use: expo start
```

**Step 4.**

Install expo app from google play store and scan QR which generate after execution of expo start command on command line then open new window into browser.

**Create project using react native init command**

**Step 1.**

Install node.js

**Step 2.**

Install the Expo CLI command line utility

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

If you create a project without expo then you need to extra setup for android and ios
Please check following [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) and go into React Native CLI Quickstart then click on to window setup

**Step 4.**

Create new project

```
react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject

react-native run-android
```

For more information about project creation please check following link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started